# jQuery Mobile - scroll to specific div on pageload

Tags: jquery-mobile

I would like to automatically scroll to a particular div when the page loads.  However, I seem to get into some conflict with JQM's scroll to top functionality.

I am using the following code:

```
$.mobile.silentScroll($("#myElementId").offset().top);
```

which does not scroll correctly when wrapped like this:

```
$('[data-role=page]').bind("pageshow", function() {
    $.mobile.silentScroll($("#myElementId").offset().top);
});
```

but works correctly with a little timeout like this:

```
$('[data-role=page]').bind("pageshow", function() {
    setTimeout(function(){$.mobile.silentScroll($("#myElementId").offset().top);},100);
});
```

the problem with the last piece of code is that it causes a flicker, with a jump to the top and then a jump down the page. Any ideas how to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `setTimeout` works because the jQuery Mobile framework remembers where you were scrolled-to if you are returning to a page you've been to before and you have to wait for their scroll to complete before running your own. You can essentially disable this feature by changing the `minScrollBack` option inside the `mobileinit` event handler to something really big:

```
<script src="[jQuery Core]"></script>
<script>
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
   $.mobile.minScrollBack = 90000;
});
</script>
<script src="[jQuery Mobile]"></script>
```

That should disable the auto-scroll that the jQuery Mobile framework does when you visit a page on a subsequent visit.

Docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/api/globalconfig.html

Comment: Thanks Jasper, but even after adding your code between jQuery core and JQM, it still doesn't work.

I don't think it is an issue with the minScrollBack, because it even happens after a complete page refresh.  At that point, JQM should not be able to remember where I was scrolled to before.

Answer (score 2):

First post on StackOverflow!

Thanks for this, I have been working on a project that uses quite a bit of custom animation for the transitions and while it took a while to get here, Jasper's answer set me in the right direction, it was just missing a bit of code:

```
<script src="[jQuery]"></script>
<script>
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.extend($.mobile, {
        minScrollBack: 90000 // turn off scrolling to position on last page
    });
});
</script>
<script src="[jQuery mobile]"></script>
```

This seemed to do the trick!

Ref: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/globalconfig.html

Answer (score 0):

You guys ever tried the answer???

It does not work unless you set $.mobile.defaultHomeScroll to your wanted scroll as well.

That is, two steps.
1. set $.mobile.minScrollBack to a large enough value.
2. at page load, set the defaultHomeScroll to desired value.

Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have to do much ... I got it working with the following on the  section.

```
<script>$(function() {$.mobile.defaultHomeScroll = $(window).scrollTop();});</script>
```